# Special/Strange behavior of Graphics in .Net for creating Pen/Brushes etc

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a user control where I create some Pens and Brushes in the controls constructor and I use them for drawing on bitmap, I am using .Net Compact Framework, I found very strange behavior of `Graphics` that if I have three `Pens` with let's say `Green, Red and Blue` and I update my Bitmap every `100 ms` then it creates `20` Pens each second means `2` `Pens` every `100 ms` and surprisingly if I have three `Pens` with same color then it only creates `1` `Pen`.

Sample Code:

```
       public MyTestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _barBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            _func1Pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
            _func2Pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
            _func3Pen = new Pen(Color.Green);
        } 

      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bmpScreen == null)
            {
                _bmpScreen = new Bitmap(ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
                _gBmp = Graphics.FromImage(_bmpScreen);    
            }

            _gBmp.Clear(Color.White);    
            DoDrawings();    
            //
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bmpScreen, 0, 0);
        }

     private void DoDrawings()
        {
            if (Data == null) return;

            switch (Data.Length)
            {
                case 1:
                    DrawGraph(Data[0].Where(val => val != Config.NO_DATA_VALUE).ToArray(), _func1Pen);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DrawGraph(Data[0].Where(val => val != Config.NO_DATA_VALUE).ToArray(), _func1Pen);
                    DrawGraph(Data[1].Where(val => val != Config.NO_DATA_VALUE).ToArray(), _func2Pen);
                    break;
                case 3:

                    DrawGraph(Data[2].Where(val => val != Config.NO_DATA_VALUE).ToArray(), _func1Pen);
                    DrawGraph(Data[0].Where(val => val != Config.NO_DATA_VALUE).ToArray(), _func2Pen);
                    DrawGraph(Data[1].Where(val => val != Config.NO_DATA_VALUE).ToArray(), _func3Pen);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

private void DrawGraph(int[] data, Pen pen)
        {
            if (data == null) return;           

            Point[] newPoints = GetDataPoints(data);
            DrawLines(newPoints, pen, _gBmp);           
        }



private void DrawLines(Point[] newPoints, Pen functionPen, Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawLines(functionPen, newPoints);
            }
```

Note: I am using `.Net Compact Framework 3.5` and my refresh rate is `100 ms`
      I am using `.Net Compact Framework Remote Performance Monitor` which tells me that `20 Pens` are created every `second`, `Number of Pens Created increases by 20 every second`.

Any idea what is causing to create `2 Pens` every time I update my bitmap?

Comment: I don't see anything in what you posted that would create more pens.  The only thing I see that could do that is if you are instantiating a new `MyTestControl` every 150 ms.  But, you haven't posted the details of `GetDataPoints`, so maybe it does something with pens.

Comment: In GetDataPoints(), I am just creating Point array nothing else.

Comment: How exactly have you determined you are getting so many pens per second being created?